# Relevant sorting in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, full-text-search, elasticsearch

Consider following schema for document `{ user_name : string, tweet : string }`. Now when search query is fired result should be sorted in such a way that tweets of certain `user_name` should appear on top while rest of the tweets at bottom.

Best use-case would of Soundcloud. When a user starts searching, sounds or users which he/she follows appear at top while rest of the content at bottom.

Is there any way to do this in elasticsearch?

***Note**: If you are able to answer it using [tire gem](https://github.com/karmi/tire) then it would be great otherwise only logic is also acceptable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push certain results to the top using [Custom Filters Score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) query. Just add user_name:certain_name as a filter with high enough boost.